# Convert default timezone to UTC

Tags: java, calendar

I have calendar object created in system timezone which is of "EDT". When ever i get the `cal.getTime();` it prints the date of EDT. How can i get the date of the same calendar in UTC?

I am just trying to convert it to string using the below snippet

```
   `Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();      
    String definedDate = CalendarUtils.toString(cal, "MM/dd/yyyy");
    System.out.println(definedDate); 


public static String toString(Calendar cal, String pattern) {
    String str = "";
    if (cal!= null) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        str = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
        LOGGER.error("Date : "+str);
    }
    return str;
}
```

`

Comment: There's a simple direct way to do that, see the linked question.

Answer (score 1):

Try Below code, set time zone to DateFormat as DateFormat.setTimeZone():

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(timeZone);
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = 
       new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US);
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(timeZone);

System.out.println("Time zone: " + timeZone.getID());
System.out.println("default time zone: " + TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
System.out.println();

System.out.println("UTC:     " + simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
System.out.println("Default: " + calendar.getTime());
```

Comment: Yes it works. Thanks for your input. how can we get the same calendar in UTC instance. here we are converting it to string.

Comment: Please mark it as solved, if it works for you.
simpleDateFormat.parse("Date in String Format") should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Get calendar instance using below snippet...

```
Calendar cal= Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Or change timezone to utc as following...

```
cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Comment: It converts only the timezone. date and time remains the same of system timezone

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
c2.set(year, month, date, hourOfDay, minute, second);
System.out.println(sdf.format(c2.getTime()));
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term value.
Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what
limitations and assumptions apply.